# How to make Jquery sortable affect other ul and list items?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to get a list to affect the position of another list using Jquery Sortable.

What I am currently working with is two separate sortable lists, but what I want to achieve is, when *Item 1* of *list 1* is moved to the bottom, *Item 1* of *list 2* is moved to the bottom as well, bearing in mind that I don't want the opposite to happen e.g. I can't move item 1 of list 2 to the bottom to affect list 1.

```
<script>
$( function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
$( "#list" ).sortable();
$( "#list" ).disableSelection(); 
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 5</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 6</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list">
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 5</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 6</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable" class="sort-list-ul">
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 5</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 6</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list" class=" sort-list-ul-no-drag">
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 5</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 6</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">
</span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

In your js :

```
     $(function () {
     $(".sort-list-ul").sortable({
         update: function (event, ui) {
             $(".sort-list-ul-no-drag").not($(this)).html($(this).html());
         }
     }).disableSelection();

   $('.sort-list-ul-no-drag').sortable();

 });
```

Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1Lcx9gnf/15/